# Searching Multi-Dimension Array With Multiple Results

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have an array and I want to search for a value should return multiple results:

```
array(2) {
  [0] => array(2) {
    ["id"] => string(2) "1"
    ["custom"] => string(1) "2"
    }
  [1] => array(2) {
    ["id"] => string(2) "2"
    ["custom"] => string(1) "5"
    }
  [2] => array(2) {
    ["id"] => string(2) "3"
    ["custom"] => string(1) "2"
    }
}
```

I want to search for key `custom` with `value = 2`, with the following result:

```
array(2) {
  [0] => array(2) {
    ["id"] => string(2) "1"
    ["custom"] => string(1) "2"
    }
  [1] => array(2) {
    ["id"] => string(2) "3"
    ["custom"] => string(1) "2"
    }
}
```

Is this possible without looping through array? Is there such class or built in function for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) function is probably what you want.

```
$array = [
    [
        'id' => '1',
        'custom' => '2'
    ],
    [
        'id' => '2',
        'custom' => '5'
    ],
    [
        'id' => '3',
        'custom' => '2'
    ]
];

$customs = array_filter(
    $array,
    function ($arr) {
        return is_array($arr) && array_key_exists('custom', $arr) && $arr['custom'] === '2';
    }
);
```

Comment: Just a remark: without array_values(), you will get

`array(2) {
  [0] => array(2) {
    ["id"] => string(2) "1"
    ["custom"] => string(1) "2"
    },
  [2] => array(2) {
    ["id"] => string(2) "3"
    ["custom"] => string(1) "2"
    }
}`

i.e. the returned array gives indexes of 0 and 2.

But the consecutive indexes probably isn't significant to you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

`array_values( array_filter($array, function($item) { return $item['custom'] == 2; }) );`

`array_values($array)` is used to return an array with indexes which is consecutive, i.e. from 0, 1, 2, ... upward.

Comment: For functions about handling array in PHP, please see:
http://php.net/manual/en/indexes.functions.php for function name starting with "array_"

Answer (score 0):

You could simply remove the values you don't want by un-setting them from the array:

```
foreach($array as $key => $item) {
    if($item['custom'] !== 2) {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }    
}
```

[**Example**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#Wm8mCWqhb)

---

<sup>*This is an alternative to `array_values()`, but essentially does it the same way.*</sup>